# I can't seem to pass arguments with spaces in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, find, chmod

I was trying to write a script for normalizing permissions in Linux:

```
for f in $(find . -type f); do
    file "$f" | grep -e "ELF 64-bit LSB executable" -e "ELF 32-bit MSB executable" > /dev/null
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        chmod -c u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx "$f"
    else
        chmod -c u=rw,g=r,o=r "$f"
    fi;
done
```

Obviously, I'm trying to pass file paths to `chmod` and I'm using double quotes as in `"$f"` but somehow still getting `No such file or directory` errors:

```
chmod: './FreeDesktop_integration/nautilus-scripts/Archiving/PeaZip/Extract''e erişilemedi: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
chmod: 'Archive''e erişilemedi: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
```

It seems `./FreeDesktop_integration/nautilus-scripts/Archiving/PeaZip/Extract Archive` gets treated as 2 files by `chmod` (and this is rather unexpected).

So what's causing this and how do I solve this (passing args properly) ?

Bonus question: Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve with the script ?

Comment: Read this from a sister site, super detailed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names

Comment: This is [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29); also the subject of [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) and *numerous* dupes here on SO (no need to refer over to unix.se)!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well thanks for the heads up but I don't see why would this question get downvoted -cuz I don't know shell scripting?

Comment: While the downvote wasn't mine, the one thing I think you *could* have done differently is running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking the question, as advised by the [`bash` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info); the wiki links given in the warnings -- such as [SC2044](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2044) -- address the problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did, (by locally installing spellcheck) but it suggested me to use `find -exec` which I couldn't manage to do.

Comment: Did you read the wiki associated with that shellcheck warning? It shows how to use `find -print0` (as the answer by janos does as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `for f in $(find . -type f)`,
the shell performs word-splitting on the output of the `find` command.
This way it's not safe to use it like you did.

You can make it safe by using a `while` loop instead:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    if file "$f" | grep -qe "ELF 64-bit LSB executable" -e "ELF 32-bit MSB executable"; then
        chmod -c u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx "$f"
    else
        chmod -c u=rw,g=r,o=r "$f"
    fi
done
```

(I also simplified the conditional a bit, along with a bunch of tips from [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy).)

Comment: (re: an attack no longer possible now that this answer is edited to use NUL-delimited output) ...as a concrete attack, consider `d=$'./foo/ \n/etc\n/'; mkdir -p "$d" && touch "$d/f"` before this script is run; you presumably don't want `/etc` to have its `+x` permissions removed.